# Comparing numbers with decimals

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers, decimal

I have an issue in AS3 where I need to compare a number of value type `Number`. I have two `Numbers`. For example, `3.10` and `3.9`

Comparing the two, 3.9 is greater than 3.10 because it drops the 0 and its like comparing `3.9` to `3.1`.

That does make sense. I've tried using value type `int` and `uint` and its the same result. Is there something I can do to compare the two values that would result in `3.10` being greater than `3.9` without having to like split at the decimal and compare `9` to `10` ?

Comment: convert the number to strings or reconstruct the numbers as 3.010, 3.009

Comment: but `3.10` and `3.1` are the same even `3.100000000` is the same

Comment: 3.9 is greater than 3.10 and 3.1 if we are talking about decimal numbers. if you are using them as  version numbers or something you need compare the 2 parts separately

Comment: @BarisUsakli: yes, I think that is the only way

Comment: Before I did that, I wanted to be sure there wasn't an easier way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

3.9 is greater than 3.10 - without splitting the decimal points there is no way that 3.10 will be considered a higher number than 3.9.

I assume you're using this for version control, so I'd just like to caution that your version compare code takes all situations into account.

Comment: its for tracking lessons and I ran into a case where where there are 10+ lessons in a chapter. I'll just have to do a bigger compare in my if statement, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**NO, but..**

If you use Strings, you could split on dots, compare each number as int.

trace(getHighestVersion("3.9", "2.10"));        // output: 3.9

```
trace(getHighestVersion("3.9", "3.10"));        // output: 3.10 
trace(getHighestVersion("3.9", "3.9"));        // output: 3.9 (same) 
trace(getHighestVersion("3.90", "3.10"));        // output: 3.90 
trace(getHighestVersion("3.9.2.1", "3.9.1.9")); //output: 3.9.1.9
trace(getHighestVersion("3.9.2.1", "3.9.3.0")); //output: 3.9.3.0

function getHighestVersion(version1:String,version2:String):String
{
    var list1:Array = version1.split(".");
    var list2:Array = version2.split(".");

    if (list1.length != list2.length) trace("not equal lengths: " + version1 + " / " + version2);

    for(var i:int = 0, leni:uint = list1.length; i < leni; i++)
    {
        var num1:uint = uint(list1[i]);
        var num2:uint = uint(list2[i]);
        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            return version1;
        }
        if (num1 < num2)
        {
            return version2;
        }
    }
    trace("both versions are equal: " + version1 + " / " + version2)
    return version1;
}
```

Comment: He said "without having to like split at the decimal" so "Yes" is not the correct answer to the question that was asked.